# Splitting characters in JAVA

Tags: java, string, split, spaces

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Friendship
{
    public static void main (String args[])
    {
        Scanner a1=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your name");
        String me=a1.nextLine();

        System.out.println(" ");

        Scanner b1=new Scanner (System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter your partners name");
        String you=b1.nextLine();

        String both=me+you;

        String [] names = both.split("\\s+");

        for(int ch1=0; ch1<names.length; ch1++)
        {
            System.out.println(names[ch1] + " ");
        }

    }
}
```

This  is not working for me. I want to break the letters as well as to remove the spaces between the words. I found this on the site but it says "String cannot be converted to int" when I run it.

**Input -**

> Your name - Snow White
>
> Your partners name - 
>       Ferdinand

```
Output-
S
n
o
w
W
h
i
t
e
F
e
r
d
i
n
a
n
d
```

Comment: Whats the sample input and expected output?. You should try `\\s+` and split doesn't accept another String (arg 2)

Comment: What does `both` contain?

Comment: Sorry, there is not enough information here to answer, or even understand your question.  You should provide a complete example that someone else can compile.  What is the declaration of `both`, for instance?  Please take some time to visit the [help] and also read [ask].

Comment: Please edit your question and add the code there.

Comment: @AmaaniJinadasa - There is no space between `me` and `you` strings

Comment: What does "break the letters" mean?

Comment: Yes. But I want to remove the spaces between the inputs of me & you if they input more than one name.

Comment: I mean split the characters

Comment: @AmaaniJinadasa - Show us sample input and expected output

Comment: Input - 1. Snow White 2. Ferdinand

Comment: I can't answer in full as it says answer too long. If the above is the input the w & W of Snow White should be like                                                                  W   (break line)                                                                                                                         w

Comment: Edit the post and add it there.

Answer (score 1):

Well, if you do have to use `split()` here's a non-standard way of doing it :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s1 = "Snow White";
    String s2 = "Ferdinand";
    String s= s1+s2;
    String[] arr = s.split("(?!\\s)"); // Thanks to Matt for correcting it.
    for(String str :  arr)
        System.out.println(str);
}
```

O/P :

```
S
n
o
w 
W
h
i
t
e
F
e
r
d
i
n
a
n
d
```

Comment: Crafty, it seem that `"(?!\\s)"` is sufficient.

Answer (score 0):

Becausde the method that you are calling i.e. 2 parameters is

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split(java.lang.String,%20int)

where the second parameter is an `int`

it sounds like you want to use `String.replaceAll (String regex, String)`

**Edit**

based upon your comment here is no space between me and you strings, so the split will not work anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

[`String.split(String)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-) doesn't take two `String` arguments.

```
String [] names = both.split("\\s+");
```

The only other version of `split` ([`String.split(String, int)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#split-java.lang.String-int-)) is what the compiler is attempting to use and a `String` is not an `int` as your error message says.

Based on your comment above, why not loop over `me` and `you` and skip any white space, building temporary `String`(s) isn't particulary efficient (especially if just want to split again and display non-whitespace characters)

```
for (char ch : me.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
for (char ch : you.toCharArray()) {
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        System.out.println(ch);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a reg-ex:

```
    Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\w");
    Matcher m = p.matcher("Snow White");
    while(m.find()){
        System.out.print(m.group());
    }
    System.out.println();
```

This would output `SnowWhite` each character is separate though.